# React JS class inheritence and class and/or state variables. I need a counter or identity value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic class structure a parent class and inherited classes.  I have looked for several options to implement this but haven't found a successful way to implement this. I would like an identity value in the base class, and have it automatically increment as each new inherited class is instantiated.  So each subclass instance has a unique id.  I have tried useState() but it's tied to actions and rendering (as far as I can tell).  Here are my simple classes.

```
class Entity {
    constructor(x, y, size, attributes) {
        this.id = {a incrementing integer value}
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.size = size
        this.attributes = { ...attributes }
    }
}
export default Entity
```

and

```
import Entity from './Entity'

class Player extends Entity {
    attributes = {
        name: 'Player',
        character: '@',
        color: '#f00',
        health: 20,
    }
}
export default Player
```

and

```
import Entity from './Entity'

class Item extends Entity {
    attributes = {
    }
}
export default Item
```

Like I said I tried useState() but it's tired to a user action or render which is not what I'm looking for.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for static properties [MDM static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

```js
class Entity {
    static _id = 0
    constructor(x, y, size, attributes) {
        this.id = Entity._id++
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.size = size
        this.attributes = { ...attributes }
       
    }
}


class Player extends Entity {
    attributes = {
        name: 'Player',
        character: '@',
        color: '#f00',
        health: 20,
    }
}

class Item extends Entity {
    attributes = {
    }
}

const player = new Player()
const item = new Item();
const item2 = new Item();

console.log(player.id);
console.log(item.id);
console.log(item2.id);
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DawsonMSchaffer you can reward me :P